# activating an aria Jquery tab from hyperlink

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I'm a bit new to Jquery so if I'm approaching this from the wrong direction please let me know.

I have a destination page that contains a Jquery based tab module. I want to activate a certain tab when a particular hyperlink on another page is clicked.

Is there any built in method to achieving this? Or will I need to place extra script on the destination page to say activate the chosen tab when a certain query string variable I define is passed through on the hyperlink?

So say the page the tab is on `www.example.com`

and the tab I want to activate is:

```
<li id="tabChangeDirectDebit" class="change-direct-debit last ui-state-  
default ui-corner-top" role="tab" aria-controls="changeDirectDebit" aria-
labelledby="ui-id-5" aria-selected="false">
    <a href="#changeDirectDebit" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" id="ui-id-5">
        <img src="~/media/images/DirectDebitTool/navigation/change-dd-amount.png?h=80&amp;w=140" class="inactive" alt="" width="140" height="80">
        <img src="~/media/images/DirectDebitTool/navigation/change-dd-amount-active.png?h=80&amp;w=140" class="active" alt="c" width="140" height="80">
        <div>
            <span>Change Direct Debit</span>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Is there something I can do quite simple by passing a query string or hashtag through on the hyperlink? Like `www.example.com#changeDirectDebit`. Or would this require additional script on the destination page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on where you will get the identifier for the active tab.

**Example 1. hash**

Lets assume that on the previous page a user clicked a link like this: `http://path/to/page/#tab3`

You will have access to that `#tab3` string in jQuery (or pure JS in fact) in `window.location.hash`.

**Example 2. GET params**
Lets assume that on the previous page a user clicked a link like this: `http://path/to/page/?active_tab=myTab`

You may use a little [snippet by Chris Coyier](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-variables/).

```
function getQueryVariable(variable) {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0; i<vars.length; i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

Using this function, you will get the identifier like so:

`var targetTab = getQueryVariable('active_tab'); //this would return *myTab* in my example`

You will need some identifier on each tab, either in the form of a data attribute, or ID, or you can use the jQuery `.index()` to find the needed tab by the identifier. Or any other way you know.

Comment: cool that makes sense. So say i capture the hashtag and store it as a variable. How would i select and then change the "aria-selected" property?